# Use dplyr to summarize but preserve date of group row

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, summarize, preserve

I have a data frame like the following:

```
          Date Flare Painmed_Use
1   2015-12-01     0           0
2   2015-12-02     0           0
3   2015-12-03     0           0
4   2015-12-04     0           0
5   2015-12-05     0           0
6   2015-12-06     0           1
7   2015-12-07     1           4
8   2015-12-08     1           3
9   2015-12-09     1           1
10  2015-12-10     1           0
11  2015-12-11     0           0
12  2015-12-12     0           0
13  2015-12-13     1           2
14  2015-12-14     1           3
15  2015-12-15     1           1
16  2015-12-16     0           0
```

I'm trying to find the length of each flare as well as the total med use during each flare using dplyr. My current solution (inspired by [Use rle to group by runs when using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246453/use-rle-to-group-by-runs-when-using-dplyr#35313426)),

```
df %>% 
    group_by(yy = {yy = rle(Flare); rep(seq_along(yy$lengths), yy$lengths)}, Flare) %>%
    summarize(Painmed_UseCum = sum(Painmed_Use),FlareLength = n())
```

gives the following output:

```
     yy Flare Painmed_UseCum FlareLength
   <int> <int>          <dbl>       <int>
 1     1     0              1           6
 2     2     1              8           4
 3     3     0              0           2
 4     4     1              6           3
 5     5     0              0           1
```

This is almost exactly what I need. However, I can't figure out how to preserve other columns, the critical one being the date that corresponds to the last row of a particular flare. So, the output I'm seeking is the same as above but with the addition of the Dates, like so:

```
           Date      yy Flare Painmed_UseCum FlareLength
                  <int> <int>          <dbl>       <int>
 1   2015-12-06       1     0              1           6
 2   2015-12-10       2     1              8           4
 3   2015-12-12       3     0              0           2
 4   2015-12-15       4     1              6           3
 5   2015-12-16       5     0              0           1
```

Note: In some ways this is a follow up from a previous question of mine ([R code to get max count of time series data by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960252/r-code-to-get-max-count-of-time-series-data-by-group)) but my attempt to keep that question simpler, though perhaps useful to others, ended up necessitating this further question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either include Date in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(yy = {yy = rle(Flare); rep(seq_along(yy$lengths),yy$lengths)}) %>%
  summarize(Painmed_UseCum = sum(Painmed_Use),FlareLength = n(), Date = max(Date))

# Groups:   yy, Flare [5]
#  Date       Flare Painmed_Use    yy
#  <date>     <int>       <int> <int>
#1 2015-12-06     0           1     1
#2 2015-12-10     1           0     2
#3 2015-12-12     0           0     3
#4 2015-12-15     1           1     4
#5 2015-12-16     0           0     5
```

Or if there are more columns to preserve better approach is to use `mutate` and select the last row in each group.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(yy = {yy = rle(Flare); rep(seq_along(yy$lengths), yy$lengths)}) %>%
  mutate(Painmed_UseCum = sum(Painmed_Use),FlareLength = n()) %>%
  slice(n())
```

---

To create groups, we can replace `rle` with `rleid` from `data.table` which would be simpler.

```
group_by(yy = data.table::rleid(Flare))
```

Comment: Wow! So helpful. Thank you again Ronak. Your answer, I think, will help me generalize as well.